# Could there be an irrational number $x$ such that the product of $x$ and $\pi$ are rational?

Tags: irrational-numbers, products, pi

I know that irrational numbers cannot be the quotients of any two rational numbers, and an irrational number times a rational number is thus also irrational.  But, could there be an irrational number, that, when multiplied by $\pi$, the product is rational?

Comment: How about $\frac 1{\pi}$?

Comment: I mean a number not derived from pi.  For example, it is not known if e*pi is irrational or rational.  Is there an irrational number where it is known that it times pi is rational?

Comment: "derived from $\pi$" doesn't mean anything.  If $\alpha\times \pi=\frac ab$ then $\alpha = \frac a{b\pi}$.

Comment: @qazwsx As lulu observed, any irrational number that satisfies the condition is of the form $\frac{a}{b\pi}$ with $a,b\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}$. That means ALL the numbers you are looking for will be numbers as $\frac{3}{2\pi}$, $\frac{17}{23\pi}$, $\frac{217}{1000\pi}$, etc. ALL will be "derived from $\pi$"

Comment: @qazwsx "*a number not derived from pi*" $\;-\;$ You can "obfuscate" it like $\frac{1}{\arctan(1)}$ for example, but it must still be a rational multiple of $\frac{1}{\pi}$.

Comment: You're probably asking, "are there two known irrational numbers whose product was expected to be irrational, but was later to shown to be rational." Unfortunately, I don't know of any such examples, and I suspect there are hardly any nontrivial answers. However, you might be interested [in this related mathoverflow page](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32967).

Answer (score 2):

If $r=x\pi$ where $r$ is rational, then we have $x=\frac r\pi$.

This means that if you have an $x$ such that $x\pi$ is rational, then $x$ is of the form $\frac k\pi$ for some rational $k$. This explains why the answer to your question should always be *"derived from $\pi$"*.